# Amazon EC2 ssh connection time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

[image]

I cannot connect to my instance via SSH. I followed the steps in the document but no luck.

I tried this way:

```
ssh -i mykeypairname.pem ec2-user@52.74.224.84
```

And it shows notice:

`ssh: connect to host 52.74.224.84 port 22: Connection timed out`

I'm sure that I've opened port 22 for all IP (see the attachment)

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Is the instance in the Default VPC, or in your own VPC? If it is your own, check that it is in a public subnet with routing rules through an Internet Gateway. You could also check the System Log (Actions->Instance Settings-> Get System Log) to see if the instance booted OK.

Answer (score 1):

After searching, I have found the solution:

I have to make a public Internet Gateway pointing to 0.0.0.0/0 in the Route Table that attached to my VPC.

I added a record in my Route Table with content:

**Destination: 0.0.0.0/0

Target: igw-14da1f71 - which is an Internet Gateway attached to my VPC**